# how to tweet a image in iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I want to tweet a image which I would be sending from my app.I am using Twitter_Oauth API for my application.
 For updating status I use:

```
    [_engine sendUpdate:@"This is my tweet"];
```

But how to tweet a image ? sorry, i didnt find any relevant documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Use [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/tutorial/twitter) It's powerful. It supports as image as text posts to Twitter (and not only - Facebook, ReadItLater and some others).

Comment: well, if your api supports your requirements, all you need is to study it's documentation. Otherwise, take ShareKit ))) it' faster than you imagine

Answer (score 0):

You can use share kit for this or you can use OAuth protocol or use can twitpic api to upload photo on twitter. you have to register your app in Twipic check out the Demo http://sourceforge.net/projects/tweetphoto/files/TestTwitpic.zip/download

The demo is working properly but some times it gone crash